# Google Analytic Content Grouping report result not showing

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

can anyone please take a look what am doing wrong, I setup google analytic for my site and created content grouping using tracking code please check screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAgrb.png
and then i added tracking code inside head tag acutally am using content grouping only on my blog single pages based on category please check code here

```
<?php
if(is_single())
    {
    ?>
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-213318186-1"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());
          <?php
              $category = get_the_category();
              $firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;
          ?>
         gtag('config', 'UA-213318186-1', {'content_group1': '<?php echo $firstCategory; ?>'});
        </script>
<?php
}
```

but am still not getting reports result in my google analytic report area please see screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjFTJ.png

Comment: What is this? `$firstCategory` - is it defined?  When you look in the page source, do you see your script, and what does it say?

Comment: Yes, its is defined, actually its dynamically generating the category associated with a post on a single page here is the link https://lakefs.io/lakefs-data-versioning-at-scale/ you can check source code though and here the generated value(Project) of $firstCategory variable gtag('config', 'UA-213318186-1', {'content_group1': 'Project'});

Comment: I followed this article (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cmodify-your-gtagjs-snippet%2Cmodify-your-android-sdk-snippet%2Cmodify-your-ios-sdk-snippet%2Cmodify-your-analyticsjs-snippet) but don't know what am doing wrong and not seeing any report in my google analytic area

Comment: Okay its showing now its start showing after 24 hours :)

Comment: I voted to close this question because you indicate that you resolved the problem without receiving any answers. If you still need answers, please [edit] the question to indicate that the issue is not fully resolved. If the solution you found would be useful to others, please answer your own question by pressing the "Answer Your Question" button.

Answer (score 0):

Its start showing report after 24 hours